# Fixed point binary and back python

Tags: python, fixed-point

I am fairly new to python is there a fast way to convert decimal to 16-bit fixed-point binary (1-bit sign – 7-bit integer – 8-bit fraction) and back in python.

I would like to manipulate the binary and convert this manipulated binary back to decimal.

Example `1.25 -> 00000001.01000000`

Manipulate first fraction part (0->1)

```
00000001.11000000 -> 1.75
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have N bits in the fractional part then you just need to divide by 2<sup>N</sup>, since the stored bit pattern is actually the real value multiplied by 2<sup>N</sup>. Therefore with Q8.8 like in your case you'll have to divide by 256

For your 00000001.01000000 and 00000001.11000000 examples above:

```
>>> 0b0000000101000000/256.0
1.25
>>> 0b0000000111000000/256.0
1.75
```

Comment: Thank you so much @phuclv . Could you also help me how to convert 1.25 to 0b0000000101000000

Comment: @AbhinavGeorge multiply it by 256, like I said above

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Binary fractions](https://pypi.org/project/binary-fractions/) package.

Example:

```
>>> from binary_fractions import Binary
>>> b = Binary(15.5)
>>> print(b)
0b1111.1
>>> Binary(1.25).lfill(8).rfill(8)
Binary(00000001.01000000, 0, False)
>>> Binary(1.75).lfill(8).rfill(8)
Binary(00000001.11000000, 0, False)
>>> Binary('0b01.110').lfill(8).rfill(8)
Binary(00000001.11000000, 0, False)
>>> Binary('0b01.110').lfill(8).rfill(8).string()
'00000001.11000000'
```

It has many more helper functions to manipulate binary strings such as: shift, add, fill, to_exponential, invert...

PS: Shameless plug, I'm the author of this package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **fxpmath** to do calculations simplier.

Info about **fxpmath**:

https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath

Your example could be solved like:

```py
from fxpmath import Fxp

x = Fxp(1.25, True, 16, 8)      # signed=True, n_word=16, n_frac=8

x.bin(frac_dot=True)
```

out:

> '00000001.01000000'

Now you can apply an OR mask to do `0` bit val to `1`:

```py
y = x | Fxp('0b01.110', True, 16, 8) 

print(y.bin(frac_dot=True))
print(y)
```

out:

> '00000001.11000000'
>   1.75

Answer (score 0):

[numfi](https://numfi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can transform floating point number to fixed point with certain word/fraction length, but directly manipulate binary bits is not possible.

You can use bitwise logical operation like and/or/xor to modify bits as workaround, for computation heavy program, bitwise operation should be faster than string evaluation

```
>>> from numfi import numfi  
>>> x = numfi(1.25,1,16,8)   
>>> x
numfi([1.25]) s16/8-r/s
>>> x.bin
array(['0000000101000000'], dtype='<U16')
>>> x.bin_
array(['11111110.11000000'], dtype='<U17')
>>> y = x | 0b0000000010000000
>>> y
numfi([1.75]) s16/8-r/s
>>> y.bin_
array(['00000001.11000000'], dtype='<U17')
```